# unnecessary variable in result from minimize in constraint logic programming with swi-prolog

Tags: swi-prolog, constraint-programming, clpq

I am following Ivan Bratkos 'Prolog programming for Artificial Intelligence fourth edition', and I'm currently reading about constraint logic programming.

In the book theres a small optimization example for task scheduling that goes like this:

```
{Ta >= 0,
Ta + 2 =< Tb,
Ta + 2 =< Tc,
Tb + 3 =< Td,
Tc + 5 =< Tf,
Td + 4 =< Tf},
minimize(Tf).
```

which in swi-prolog results in

```
Ta = 0,
Tb = 2,
Td = 5,
Tf = 9,
{_G371>=0, _G377=2-_G371, _G371=<2, Tc=4-_G371}.
```

The result is fine (even though it would have been prettier if it had just written {Tc =< 4} {Tc >= 2} like in the book), but I don't understand why it adds the '_G377=2-_G371' part, -it seems very unnecessary...

**why is this extra variable (_G377) added to the result?**

*in case someone else is reading the book: I have changed the 'Ta =< 0' to 'Ta >= 0', as I believe the 'Ta =< 0' is an error in the book.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you show suggests that you are using `library(clpq)` and not `library(clpr)`. In the original implementation of this library in SICStus Prolog, I get:

```
| ?- {Ta >= 0,
Ta + 2 =< Tb,
Ta + 2 =< Tc,
Tb + 3 =< Td,
Tc + 5 =< Tf,
Td + 4 =< Tf},
minimize(Tf).     
Ta = 0,
Tb = 2,
Td = 5,
Tf = 9,
{Tc=<4},
{Tc>=2} ? 
yes
```

So this seems to be a bug in SWI. Probably some variables have not been projected away.